# Select para subtrair valor atual do anterior e retornar coluna com resultado

Tags: mysql, select

Tenho duas tabelas: Amostras e Valores, que tem colunas conforme segue:

**TABELA Amostras**

```
Amostra_id 
Data 
Operador_Id
Carta_Id
```

**TABELA Valores**

```
Amostra_Id 
Valor
```

Como podem ver, a tabela Valores se relaciona com a tabela Amostras a partir de Amostra_id.
Operador_Id e Carta_Id vem de outras tabelas que não vem ao caso.

O que preciso é o seguinte: Preciso ter um *SELECT* que me de como retorno a Data, Valor e além disso uma coluna chamada de AMPLITUDE. A AMPLITUDE é o valor menos o valor anterior.

Vou tentar exemplificar:

```
VALOR     l 60   l 50   l 30   l 80   
AMPLITUDE l 10   l 20   l -50  l
```

Obs: Banco de dados MySQL.

---

Tentei o seguinte para obter uma coluna deslocada da outra (fiz isso, pois depois faço o cálculo da amplitude a partir dessas colunas):

```
Select * from(
         select *, curRank := @curRank + 1 as rank
         from(
              select * from valores
              left join (amostras)
                     on (amostras.AMOSTRAS_ID like valores.AMOSTRAS_AMOSTRAS_ID)
              order by amostras.AMOSTRAS_ID desc
          ) t, (select @curRank := 0) r
          where t.CARTA_CARTA_ID = 2
 )
 left join 
 (
         select u.valor as value2, @curRank  := @curRank + 1 as rank from
         (
                select * from valores
                left join (amostras)
                       on (amostras.AMOSTRAS_ID like valores.AMOSTRAS_AMOSTRAS_ID)
                order by amostras.AMOSTRAS_ID desc
         ) u, (select @curRank :=0) r
         where u.CARTA_CARTA_ID = 2
         limit 1,25
  ) x
  on (v.rank like x.rank)
```

Eu havia esquecido de explicar, mas meu select só deve retornar os últimos 25 valores - por isso utilizei LIMIT.

Nesse Select que fiz, parece estar muito próximo, porém os dados do segundo select (value2 e rank - do left join) retorna tudo como NULL.
Talvez meu erro esteja em usar *left join*.

Alguma idéia? 
Grato.

Comment: Jhon, favor esclarecer se a amplitude ficou desalinhada depois da formatação. Se positivo, favor [edit] para corrigir.

Comment: Está ok. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

É possível fazer com uma variável:

```
select *, ( v.valor - @lastValue ) as amplitude,
      @lastValue := v.valor
   from
      valores v,
      ( select @lastValue := 0 ) SQLVars
   order by
      v.amostra_id
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2ea86/1

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo Jader. Na resposta a seguir vou tentar explicar melhor minha dúvida.

Comment: @Jhon edita essa mesma pergunta e corrige, pois o que entendi foi isso... (amplitude = valor - valor anterior) é o que a query esta fazendo.

Answer (score 0):

Enfim consegui com o código abaixo:

```
select d.rank, d.DATA, d.VALOR, z.VALOR2, ABS(d.VALOR - z.VALOR2) AMPLITUDE
from (
    select * from
       (
        select *, @curRank :=@curRank + 1 as rank
        from 
        (
            select * from valores
            left join (amostras) 
            on (amostras.AMOSTRAS_ID like valores.AMOSTRAS_AMOSTRAS_ID)
            ORDER BY amostras.DATA desc
        ) a, (select @curRank :=0) b
        where a.CARTA_CARTA_ID = ? (id desejado aqui)                
        limit 0,25 (limitando nas 25 amostras)
       ) c
     ) d
(select VALOR2, rank as r from(
     select v.valor as VALOR2, @curRank := @curRank + 1 as rank
     from(
          select * from valores  
          left join (amostras)
          on (amostras.AMOSTRAS_ID like valores.AMOSTRAS_AMOSTRAS_ID)
          order by amostras.DATA desc   
         ) v, (select @curRank :=0) x
      where v.CARTA_CARTA_ID = ? (id desejado aqui)
      limit 1,25) y
 ) z
 where z.r like d.rank
```

Isso aí!